# show login dialog before mainwindow and hide mainwindow button

Tags: c++, qt

I want a login dialog before mainwindow so if user is not admin hide some button on mainwindow. My login form is frmLogin.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        QApplication a(argc, argv);


    QSplashScreen *splash = new QSplashScreen;
    splash->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/pic/salek.jpg"));
    splash->show();

    QFile styleFile( ":/css/coffee.qss" );
    styleFile.open( QFile::ReadOnly );


    QString style( styleFile.readAll() );

    MainWindow w;

    QTimer::singleShot(2500,splash,SLOT(close()));
    QTimer::singleShot(2500,&w,SLOT(show()));

    w.setStyleSheet( style );



    //w.show();
    w.setFixedSize(w.size());

    return a.exec();
}
```

---

```
frmLogin::frmLogin(QWidget parent,MainWindow mainWindow) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::frmLogin) {
 ui->setupUi(this); 

} 

frmLogin::~frmLogin() { 

    delete ui; 
} 

void frmLogin::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    MainWindow mainwidow; this->hide(); mainwidow.show(); 
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I made my program with Mainwindow. mainwindow show first i want a login dialog before it. And when i push the button on the dialog hide some button on mainwindow and be hiden and mainwindow shows.

Comment: Where is this dialog?

Comment: I don't know how to call it and get mainwindows ui elements from it.

Comment: show frmLogin code

Comment: frmLogin::frmLogin(QWidget *parent,MainWindow* mainWindow) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::frmLogin)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

frmLogin::~frmLogin()
{
    delete ui;
}

void frmLogin::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    MainWindow mainwidow;
    this->hide();
    mainwidow.show();
}

Comment: edit your question and add this. :)

Comment: BTW adjust the intention of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you do not know about OOP, when you use:

```
MainWindow mainwidow;
```

You are creating a window different from the main.cpp, in addition to being a local variable will be deleted. frmLogin should not know about the existence of MainWindow, a way of signaling that it has been correctly logged is to emit a signal:

**frmlogin.h**

```
#ifndef FRMLOGIN_H
#define FRMLOGIN_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class frmLogin;
}

class frmLogin : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit frmLogin(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~frmLogin();
signals:
    void adminSignal();
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
private:
    Ui::frmLogin *ui;
};

#endif // FRMLOGIN_H
```

**frmlogin.cpp**

```
...

void frmLogin::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if(/*verify is Admin*/){
        emit adminSignal();
        close();
    }
}
```

and then in the main.cpp we will use that signal:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSplashScreen splash;
    splash.setPixmap(QPixmap(":/pic/salek.jpg"));
    splash.show();

    QFile styleFile( ":/css/coffee.qss" );
    styleFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString style(styleFile.readAll());

    MainWindow w;
    w.setStyleSheet( style );
    frmLogin login;

    QTimer::singleShot(2500,&splash, &QSplashScreen::close);
    QTimer::singleShot(2500,&login, &QSplashScreen::show);
    QObject::connect(&login, &frmLogin::adminSignal, &w, &MainWindow::show);

    return a.exec();
}
```

---

Update:

If you want to do one action or another depending on a condition then you must pass a flag through the signal, and in MainWindow you implement a method that takes care of that task depending on the flag.

**mainwindow.h**

```
...
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    void enableButtons(bool isAdmin);
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::enableButtons(bool isAdmin){
    your_button->setEnabled(isAdmin);
}
```

**frmLogin.h**

```
...
signals:
    void adminSignal(bool);
```

**frmLogin.cpp**

```
void frmLogin::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if(/*verify is Admin*/)
        emit adminSignal(true);
    else
        emit adminSignal(false);
    close();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
QTimer::singleShot(2500,&splash, &QSplashScreen::close);
QTimer::singleShot(2500,&login, &QSplashScreen::show);
QObject::connect(&login, &frmLogin::adminSignal, [&w](bool isAdmin){ 
    w.show();
});
QObject::connect(&login, &frmLogin::adminSignal, &w, &MainWindow::enableButtons);
```

Comment: How to deactivate  pushbotton on mainwindow if condition on frmLogin not meet ?

Comment: We have admin user and user. Admin user has all access to the programs buttons.

Comment: Is it possible to make Mainwindow parent of frmLogin and access ui elements ?

Comment: @BehruzMontazeri 
ui elements of MainWindow are private attributes so you can not access them even if you pass the same MainWindow, it also smells bad design, in Qt the use of signals is preferred.

Comment: Almost there. but i get this error : error: no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(frmLogin*, <unresolved overloaded function type>, MainWindow*, void (QWidget::*)())'
     QObject::connect(&login, &frmLogin::adminSignal, &w, &MainWindow::show);
                                                                           ^

Comment: Still has problem.: error: expected ';' before '}' token
     });
     ^

Comment: @BehruzMontazeri change `w.show()` to `w.show();`, see my update

Comment: : no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(frmLogin*, <unresolved overloaded function type>, qMain(int, char**)::<lambda(bool)>)'
     });
      ^

Comment: @BehruzMontazeri 
Have you made all the modifications that I have proposed in my update? Could you show me your code?

Comment: QTimer::singleShot(2500,splash,SLOT(close()));
    QTimer::singleShot(2500,&login,SLOT(show()));
    QObject::connect(&login, &frmLogin::adminSignal, [&w](bool isAdmin){
        w.show();
    });
    QObject::connect(&login, &frmLogin::adminSignal, &w, &MainWindow::enableButtons);

Comment: @BehruzMontazeri 
upload it to your github to download and try it, I think you have not made all the modifications.

Comment: @BehruzMontazeri the repo is empty

Comment: See it now. I added files.

Comment: @BehruzMontazeri share the Poem.db

Comment: Ok. It's there.

Comment: @BehruzMontazeri I have already made the changes, I have added other necessary changes

Comment: I saw the changes.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create the frmLogin window from a CDialog class. Then create the object of frmLogin before MainWindow and the show the dialog with showModal flag. This make the dialog wait till user enters data and press OK button. 
Create an init function in MainWindow and pass the dialog return values to MainWindow object, based on which you can enable/disable components in MainWindow.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QPushButton>

class MyWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyWindow() :
        QMainWindow(),
        mButton(new QPushButton("Told you say hello"))
    {
        setCentralWidget(mButton);
    }

protected:
    void showEvent(QShowEvent *event) override {
        const QString& s = QInputDialog::getText(this, "", "Say Hello");
        mButton->setVisible(s != "Hello");
        QMainWindow::showEvent(event);
    }
private:
    QPushButton* mButton;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```